# trigger to check duplicate record not working

Tags: trigger

When duplicate record found based on either Phone or Email then only duplicateRecord(Checkbox field) should be checked.

I wrote the trigger to check duplicate record based on Phone or email but it is not working. It will check the checkbox even if the new created record is not duplicate

```
trigger Duplicate on Lead (before insert,before update) {

Set<String> leadEmail = new Set<String>();
Set<String> leadPhone = new Set<String>();
for(Lead leadRecords : [SELECT Id,Email,Phone FROM Lead WHERE Email != NULL OR Phone != NULL]){
    leadEmail.add(leadRecords.email);
    leadPhone.add(leadRecords.phone);
}
for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
{
    if(lead.email != null || lead.phone != null){
        if(leadEmail.Contains(lead.email) || leadPhone.contains(lead.phone)){
            lead.duplicateRecord__c = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Querying all leads is a terrible idea. This functionality will not work on a large system. Why are you not pursuing OOB duplicate management?

Answer (score 1):

In your query

```
[SELECT Id,Email,Phone FROM Lead WHERE Email != NULL OR Phone != NULL]
```

You can select a Lead with `null` Email or Phone because of `OR` (i.e. Email is null and Phone is 777)
Then you add that `null` to your Set and again because of `||` you will populate your checkbox.

To fix this you can for example add a check for `null` where you are adding records to a Set:

```
if(leadRecords.email != null){
    leadEmail.add(leadRecords.email);
}
if(leadRecords.phone != null){
    leadPhone.add(leadRecords.phone);        
}
```

Also before coding anything you can consider using built-in functionality as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I tried this also but till same problem facing me

Comment: Have you tried using debug logs and see what fields are in your set and what are in the new Lead?

Comment: I am not getting what actually  I've to do

Comment: I've noticed that you have a before update trigger, so in update case you will always add email or phone of a Lead to your Set and your checkbox will be always true. Try adding to your query `(Email != NULL OR Phone != NULL) AND Id NOT in :Trigger.new`